# How to write animated GIF to iOS camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

How do you write an animated GIF to the iOS camera roll? I understand that the photo gallery app is not able to play animations, but for example I should be able to import it when sending an email, etc.

I've tried:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData], nil, nil, nil);
```

But this seems to convert it to a jpg.

Comment: You can save GIF using PHPhotoLibrary.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115672/8484047)

Comment: You can save GIF using PHPhotoLibrary <https://stackoverflow.com/a/54115672/8484047>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `ALAssetLibrary` instance. Use this method with your `NSData`: `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score -3):

You can use gif in iOS email attachment like this.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@""];

// Attach an image to the email
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your image name" ofType:@"gif"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/gif" fileName:@"photo name"];

NSString *emailBody = @"";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```