# Save gif to iOS Photo Library in Swift

Tags: ios, image, save, gif, photolibrary

I'm traing to save a GIF image located in temp file already created with Regift code.

Regift: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift

The thing is that after saving with PHPhotoLibrary the GIF become a still image.

In other questions there's answers that refeer AssetsLibrary but this has been deprecated by Apple and doesn't work for iOS 10.

Questions:

[Save GIF image from URL to Camera Roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186219/save-gif-image-from-url-to-camera-roll)

[How to write animated GIF to iOS camera roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499513/how-to-write-animated-gif-to-ios-camera-roll)

None of this answers works... I just want to convert an image to gif and save it to camera roll... Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Have you saved your GIF into Photo Library? If yes then Please Help, I also want to store GIF into Photo Library.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I get it. let me search the project and upload it to git. Soon I share you the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can save GIF via PHPhotoLibrary.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
    request.addResource(with: .photo, fileURL: 'YOUR_GIF_URL', options: nil)
}) { (success, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("GIF has saved")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. But I have to change to use `request.addResource(with: .photo, data: data, options: nil)` to prevent it throws `NSCocoaErrorDomain`.

Answer (score 0):

Gif can be save through Activity ViewController. Give url in activity controller and save through that you will get gif in camera roll
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DdXUIjuAk0&feature=youtu.be]

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [url],
        applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```